# Multiple GCM Registration IDs for the same user sending push notifications multiple times

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-dynamodb

In the backend I receive GCM *Registration_id*, *user_id* (unique), *latitude*, *longitude*, *score* etc from **Android application** and save in the **Amazon DynamoDB** table. When I want to send push notifications to all the mobiles, I fetch all the GCM registration IDs, put into a java.util.set to avoid duplicates and then send Push Notifications to all those android devices based on set of registration IDs.

But now the ***problem*** is, Since whenever user *uninstall* and *install* the android application again, new registration_id will be generated and I receive it & save in database. Hence, same user receive push notifications multiple number of times, and it's because of multiple GCM Registration_ids saved for same user.

How do I solve this problem in the backend? I want to send only one push notification for every user. I am using Java Spring framework? Any example code and code to query DynamoDB will be highly helpful. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep one entry of GCM Registration_id against each user in the database, whenever a  user loagin or Install an application at that time you should send GCM Registration_id to the server and replace the older one with new id... check the following link

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html#Expressions.Modifying.UpdateExpressions

Comment: Yes you are right, I need to maintain separate table for Registration_id against each user in the database and I should update whenever registration_id changes for any user. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can I use 'DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client); Table item = new Table( );  item.setColumn("value"); mapper.save(item);' .  instead of using update query? According to my understanding, mapper.save(item); saves the item if item is not exists in table. But if it exists, it just updates it instead of creating another new entry. Is it correct? Am I right? Because I feel update query is tough for me in Dynamodb.

Comment: Hey i have not worked on DynamoDB db, but logically best way is to update an entry.. Best of luck with that..